# Accepted Answer Below Other Question?

Tags: support, answers, accepted-answer, sorting, answer-order

I was looking at [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/39760/console-ftps-not-sftp-client), and noticed that:

1. The accepted answer was below another answer.
2. It's not like the other answer had more votes, it had the same amount of votes.
3. The accepted answer is by the asker (which I though wasn't possible).

Screenshot here:

[image: screenshot]

Is it something to do with the fact that the asker answered and accepted their own question and answer?

Comment: Carl Hörberg is the OP of that question.

Comment: @muru... is that important?

Comment: Yes. Self-answered posts' accepted status don't count towards sorting, only the score does. See linked post.

Comment: You didn't need to flag it! I just clicked the self-duplicate button thing.

Comment: O.o It's because I flagged it that you got the self-duplicate button thing.

Comment: Not all flags are bad. For lower-rep users, that's the only way to mark something as a dupe. Chill.

Comment: @muru O.o xD right okay

Comment: @Catija, I'm a low rep user :`(

Comment: So is muru... which is why it was a flag instead of a close vote.

Comment: @Catija, oh right, okay. Thanks! :)